# time command stdout not working

Tags: command, time

I ran the time command on Linux and redirected the output to a file

```
time > time.out
```

The above command didn't work. The output time command was displayed on the terminal, the file named 'time.out' was created but empty.
I then tried `time 2> time.out`
This also didn't work, it had a similar effect as the first command I ran.

What I was trying to do was to redirect the output of time command into a file using redirection operator
Every other command I've run similarly works without any problems